# jQuery Toggle -- What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get this to work but it doesn't want to: http://jsfiddle.net/b9ecoefy/1/

Basically I'd like the DIV to show when the `li > h4 > a` is clicked

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.item div').hide();
  $('.item a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // hide all divs
    var $this = $(this).parent().find('div');
    $(".item div").not($this).hide();
    // toggle
    $this.toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <h4><a href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a></h4>
    <div class="type">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4><a href="#">Test</a></h4>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <h4><a href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a></h4>
    <div class="date">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <h4><a href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a></h4>
    <div class="type">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check what `$(this)` is - it is the link. So `$(this).parent()` is the `h4`. The `h4` does not contain any `div`s so your code will not do what you want.

Comment: `$(event.target).closest('.item').siblings('.item').hide();`

Comment: I don't see div tags (parent.find('div')

Comment: Also, if you're getting a `$ is undefined` error in the console, try editing `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {...});` to be `jQuery(document).ready(function($){...}(jQuery));`. You're passing `jQuery` as the function's `$` argument.

Comment: @RyanSchuster Not necessary. The ready callback passes jQuery as the first argument to the callback.

Comment: @doug65536 The whole construction is probably a bit unnecessary. Since passing `$` to the callback works, that means that `jQuery` is already defined as `$`, so can't user just say `$(document).ready(function() {...});` instead?

Comment: @RyanSchuster The purpose of it is to allow you to concisely use the full name jQuery at the top of your file, when you call `jQuery.ready`, then inside the callback, you can use the jQuery that it passed in, with a shorthand name, like $. This has another bigger purpose too: if another script file loads another jquery and/or messes it up, then you will continue to safely use the one that was active at the moment your code loaded.

Comment: @doug65536 I get what you're saying about the user defining `jQuery` as `$` inside the scope of that particular function, but 1) Is `jQuery` not also already defined as `$` outside the scope of that function and 2) If it's not, then don't I need to pass `jQuery` into that function (like `function($){...}(jQuery)`) so that it knows what `$` represents?

Comment: @RyanSchuster If you use `window.$` (the "global" one) then other code can trample it anytime (newly loaded jquery won't have your plugins). $ is not always jQuery, there are other libraries that use it. You should always capture the value of jQuery at startup and use that, never rely on globals to stay stable.

Comment: @doug65536 Got it. Thanks for that explanation. Was asking bc I never understood why this whole construction was necessary. So my other question is doesn't the user need to pass `jQuery` into the function like so: `function($){...}(jQuery)`? Otherwise, couldn't the code inside function have trouble knowing what `$` is, especially if it gets corrupted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this).parent().find('div');` won't work because [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) looks at descendants and you want the sibling, so use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) instead.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.item div').hide();
  $('.item h4 a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // hide all divs
    var $this = $(this).parent().next('div');
    $(".item div").not($this).hide();
    // toggle
    $this.toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <h4><a href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a></h4>
    <div class="type">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h4><a href="#">Test</a></h4>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <h4><a href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a></h4>
    <div class="date">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <h4><a href="javascript:void(0)">Test</a></h4>
    <div class="type">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Test</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works (THANK YOU!) but I'm unable to click the links within the UL

Comment: Fixed. Change the selector to `$('.item h4 a')` so it doesn't get applied to the child links